# VBA - copy & paste formula as a value as inserts row

Tags: excel, vba

Excel 2016 - when the user enters "CRED" in column D require Excel to copy the entire row and insert on the next line.

The below code inserts the next line AOK including a new code of RECMER (Column D).  In addition to this I need it to copy/paste the formula (Column C) as a value in the same column on the next line.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo errHnd

'Don't do anything if more than one cell has been changed
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

'Determine if the changed cell is in Column C and is a Y
If Target.Column = 4 Then
    If Target = "CRED" Then
        'Disable events so code doesn't fire again when row is inserted
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        'Copy & Insert changed Row, Clear dotted lines
        Target.EntireRow.Copy
        Range("A" & Target.Row + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        'Put 2201 in Column B of inserted Row
        Range("D" & Target.Row + 1) = "RECMER"
    End If
End If

errHnd:
'Re-enable event
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo errHnd

'Don't do anything if more than one cell has been changed
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

'Determine if the changed cell is in Column C and is a Y
If Target.Column = 4 Then
    If Target = "CRED" Then
        'Disable events so code doesn't fire again when row is inserted
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        'Copy & Insert changed Row, Clear dotted lines
        Target.EntireRow.Copy
        Range("A" & Target.Row + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        'Put 2201 in Column B of inserted Row
        Range("D" & Target.Row + 1) = "RECMER"

        ' ======= Added the 2 lines of code below =======
        ' copy >> paste special values only from Column C
        Range("C" & Target.Row).Copy
        Range("C" & Target.Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
End If

errHnd:
'Re-enable event
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```